# How to retrieve view outside the controller

Tags: sapui5

If I use `this.getView()` inside the controller of a view I can retrieve it without problems.

How can I retrieve the view if I am outside the controller (e. g. in controller of another view)?

I try `sap.ui.core.Core().byId("<name of view>")` but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve view from controller of another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24927206/how-to-retrieve-view-from-controller-of-another-view)

Comment: @nicolass This question is older and has better answers. Please consider flagging that other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24927206/5846045) as a duplicate instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate another view using:

```
var view = sap.ui.jsview("<name of view>");
```

If you´re using different view types you can choose the necessary function from [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html).

To avoid multiple instantiation you could do something like this:

```
var view = sap.ui.getCore().byId("id");

if (view === undefined) {
    view = sap.ui.jsview("id", "<name of view>");
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20420734/1969374) for more details regarding view definition/instantiation and IDs.

Comment: ok, it works! Now I modify the view, but the changes not show (if I modify the view into `onInit` function the view updates).
How can i refresh the view after editing?

Comment: Can you describe where your want to make what kind of modifications?

Comment: I have a view "OperationDetail".
Into controller i have onInit function and another funtion called "showTable"; it add a table to the view.

If i call this.showTable() inside onInit function i wiew the table in output, but if i want call it outside the onInit function (example in another controller) by sap.ui.xmlview("appIntra.detail.OperationDetail").getController().showTable() I do not see any tables in output.

Comment: I see. Make sure, that you always use only one instance of the view in a remote controller. Calling `sap.ui.xmlview("appIntra.detail.OperationDetail")` will always return you a new instance. So assign the return value of `sap.ui.xmlview()` to one local variable where you use it and call functions on it like `view.getController().showTable()` since this call will be on your displayed view and not on a new one. If you assigned an ID to your view you can use `sap.ui.getCore().byId("<id>").getController().showTable()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

When I create a view i set a id

```
var theView=sap.ui.xmlview("OperationDetail, "<name of view>");
```

then i retrieve it by id

```
var theView = sap.ui.core.Core().byId("OperationDetail");
var myPage=theView.byId("pageOperation");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
varRequired = sap.ui.getCore().byId("<name of view>");
```

`this` keyword refers to only the particular controller where as `sap.ui.getCore()` refers to the project views.