# How to retrieve view from controller of another view?

Tags: sapui5

I am just wondering how can I get one of the UI5 views in an application.

I know there is a method:

```js
sap.ui.jsview(); // in case the view is written in JavaScript
```

But the problem with this method is: if you assign ID for any of the controls and you have already inflated this view, you get an error.

So I want to know how to check if the view already exists and then if yes return that existing view, otherwise create the view with the corresponding API such as the above one.

I also know in the control for view I can go

```js
this.getView();
```

But as I said, how to get this view from another view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve View outside the controller - Openui5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267621/how-to-retrieve-view-outside-the-controller-openui5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite understanding your question

With managed object id's are unique, so if you try and create the same view twice you will get an error.

when you create your view the easiest way to access it is via an Id

```
 sap.ui.jsview("view1",'testapp.view.view1');
 sap.ui.getCore().byId('view1');
```

NB. views should not talk to anyone other than their controller [A terrific Model View Controller (MVC) diagram](http://alvinalexander.com/uml/uml-model-view-controller-mvc-diagram)

Comment: Thanks Jasper
that is what I need. I will look at your link but My app is like pressing one button and going to another view. How can I achieve this by not calling one view in another one?

Comment: The function which is called at the button press *is* in the controller, right? It should certainly not be in the view, so you already gave the answer yourself ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId(<id_of_the_view>)
```

Where <id_of_the_view> can be obtained in the following way:

suppose that the corresponding controller of <id_of_the_view> is "controllerA.js",
then you can console.log, inside controllerA.js,

```
console.log(this.getView())
```

This will print you an object which contains the id of such view. This will be <id_of_the_view>

Answer (score -1):

I think here is one solution.

Make a global variable;

Use it to create element.

In First View:

```
var mytextField ;(use it as global)

mytextField = new sap.ui.commons.TextField('textfieldId');
```

In Second View:

```
var myValue = mytextField .getValue();
```

~Mansi Rao