# sap.ui.getCore().byId() returns no element

Tags: sapui5

I created an UI5 app and now want to use `sap.ui.getCore().byId(id)` to access existing controls. In the same controller/view I can access them via `this.byId(id)`, but to access controls in other files (e.g. controllers) I need `sap.ui.getCore().byId(id)`.

However, while `sap.ui.getCore()` returns a core object, I cannot access controls via the `byId()` function of it, I get `undefined` instead. I already built an UI5 app and there I have no issue with this function call.

Is there something I have to configure for this to work?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24267621/how-to-retrieve-view-outside-the-controller-openui5

Comment: Thanks but my controls have ids and they already exist. My problem is that sap.ui.getCore().byId() just won't work for some reason. I have other applications where it does work as intended, but I can't figure out why in this app it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post the code for where it _is_ working and where it isn't..

Comment: To check why it doesn't work we need to see the related code but generally I would avoid to let other controllers change a view they're not responsible for. A more decoupled way could be to use the EventBus to publish that something has happenend and let the responsible controller subscribe to and handle it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look into the view's `byId`-method, you can see that it prepends the views ID, it essentially calls `sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId(id))`.

This is so that you can instantiate a view several times without having duplicate IDs. In order to access the controls from the outside, you either need the view so you can call `view.byId(id)`, or you have to manually concatenate the view's ID with the ID like this: `sap.ui.getCore().byId(viewId + "--" + id)`.

Comment: I was under the impression that with sap.ui.getCore().byId("xxx"), I can retrieve a control with the id xxx anywhere. The viewId is part of the DOM id, but not of the control id since there can only be one control with the id xxx at any time in my opinion.

Comment: It's the other way around: All control-IDs are unique. You can get any control by calling sap.ui.getCore().byId(id). When you create a control in a view (for example in XML), the id you put in the XML is prepended with the view's id in order to create a unique one. Example: new sap.m.Button("abc") creates a Button with the ID "abc". In an XML-view with id "def" a button with the ID "abc" will be created as "def--abc".

Comment: Yes, but the def-abc will be the DOM Id that is not relevant for sap.ui.getCore().byId if I'm right. So I should get the button with the sap.ui.getCore.byId("abc") in the controller? But that doesn't work for me somehow in my app.

Comment: No. The global Id MUST be unique, so you cannot create two controls with the ID "abc", that's exactly why we prefix it with the view's ID. Usually the DOM-Id is the same as the control's ID.

You can test that by creating the control with ID "abc" in an XML view, then call in the controller: this.byId("abc").getId() and you will get the real ID that can be used with sap.ui.getCore().byId().

Comment: Now I get it, thanks!

For people with that problem in the future, here is the Doc link:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f28be26f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

Comment: But I found that if you deploy project to HCP/FLP, it will change viewId, and `this.createId(id)` is only work for specific controller `this` scope.

Comment: createId() always works relative to the View/Controller on which it is called. This does not change depending on the deployment target.