# Why local Unique IDs inconsistent with IDs in HCP?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have inspect the element in app that run local in HCP, the id is `application-MaintainMasterData-display-component---addRoute--form`, but when I deploy to cloud, the id changed to `application-MaintainFleet-Display-component---addRoute--form`

The app name changed, and the `display` in the upper class way, which makes my `sap.ui.getCore().byId()` failed in cloud. I was confussing why this happens.

I've read the ref, I was in a Event handler, I need the oEvent scope, so `this.getView().byId()` and `this.createId()` won't works for me.

Ref:

[sap.ui.getCore().byId() returns no element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021011/sap-ui-getcore-byid-returns-no-element)

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f28be26f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

=========UPDATE=========

I also tried `sap.ui.getCore().byId("application-MaintainMasterData-display-component---addRoute").byId("form")` , but the same issue , `view id` is `application-MaintainFleet-Display-component---addRoute` in cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDs are dynamically generated. So you cannot rely on them. That's why you should not use `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`. Even the separators `--` and `---` may change in the future.

You should always use the `byId()` method of the nearest view or component to resolve local ids. You can chain the calls: `component.byId("myView").byId("myControl")`

In your eventhandler `this` should refer to the controller. For XMLViews this should be the case without further doing.

So i guess you are using JSViews? If you attach an eventhandler in code you can always supply a second argument to the `attachWhatever()` functions: The Object that becomes `this` in the event handler.

```js
Controller.extend("myView", {
  onInit:function(){
    var button = this.byId("button1");
    button.attachPress(this.onButtonPress, this); //The second parameter will become 'this' in the onButtonPress function
  },
  onButtonPress: function(oEvent){
    console.log(this); //this is the controller
    var buttonPressed = oEvent.getSource(); //get the control that triggered the event.
    var otherControl = this.byId("table"); //access other controls by id
    var view = this.getView(); //access the view
  }
});
```

If you are using the settings-object-syntax you can supply an array for the events. It should contain the handler function and the object that should become `this`:

```js
createContent:function(oController){
  return new Button({
    text: "Hello World",
    press: [ 
      function(oEvent){ console.log(this); }, //the event handler
      oController //oController will be 'this' in the function above
    ]
  });
```

If you are attaching to a non-UI5-event you can always use a closure to supply the view or controller to the handler function:

```js
onInit:function(){
  var that = this; //save controller reference in local variable
  something.on("event", function(){ console.log(that); }); 
                //you can use that local variable inside the eventhandler functions code.
}
```

Comment: I tried `deleteIcon.attachPress(this.onDeleteStop, this);`   but in `onDeleteStop : function(oEvent, oController){return oController}` , `oController` is `undefined`, I think I didn't get the point of `settings-object-syntax` ?

Comment: it should be `onDeleteStop: function(oEvent)  { console. log(this); }`. *this* is your controller or whatever *this* was that you supplied to the attach... function.

Comment: I've added an code example for attachPress to my answer .

Comment: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Button.html#attachPress  According to the API, is `this` the third parameter: `oListener? Context object to call the event handler with. Defaults to this sap.m.Button itself`  ?

Comment: the first parameter *oData* is optional. so the parameter after the function gets *oListener*