# Not able to toggle ui5 button

Tags: sapui5

```
new sap.m.Button("manualimage",{
                icon : 'resources/Green.JPG',
                width : "40px",
                height : "40px",
                press :function(e) { 
                    var myBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("manualimage");
                    console.log(document.getElementById("manualimage").icon);
                    myBtn.setIcon('');
                }
            })
```

When I click on the button the Icon is not changing, any suggestions what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my code which is working ( on UI5 version 1.42).
I only find one mistake : You should use ToggleButton to keep the state of Button. Say remove image if pressed or set image back when pressed back ( ie. not pressed).

Code in XML :

```
<ToggleButton icon='./images/ICICI.png' text ='hey' pressed='false' press='handlePress' />
```

Code in Controller:

```
handlePress: function(evt) {
        var oSource = evt.getSource()
        var bPressed = oSource.getPressed();
        if(bPressed) {
            oSource.setIcon('');
        } else {
            oSource.setIcon('./images/ICICI.png');
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @ArmoghanAbbas Glad I could help. Mark question as answered pls:)

Answer (score 0):

When you use:

```
var myBtn = sap.ui.getCore().byId("manualimage");
```

your var myBtn is undefined, because using sap.ui.getCore() id of button is expecting something like:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("__xmlview1--manualimage");
```

where __xmlview1-- is autogenerated by framework. So please use this code instead:

```
var myBtn = this.byId("manualimage");
```

Comment: this.byId is used when you have used XML view or the createId method of controller. Please check my reply in this below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437236/sapui5-js-in-controller-table-is-not-binding

Comment: thanks Jaro, that is not the case here.

f {bAllowTextSelection: true, mEventRegistry: Object, sId: "manualimage", mProperties: d, mAggregations: Object…}

I tried printing myBtn in console & got the above output, so myBtn is getting the input it is supposed to get. I think myBtn.setIcon('') is not working properly.

Comment: @ArmoghanAbbas : Do you mean it's not toggling the image on clicks or you mean its not removing the image after first click itself ?

Comment: @Rahul: it's not doing anything at all even after multiple clicks